# Helm Install Failure on "kind not set" Despite Passing helm lint Without Errors

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm facing an issue when trying to deploy a Helm chart to my Kubernetes cluster. Despite the chart passing helm lint without any errors, running the helm install command results in an installation failure, citing an inability to build Kubernetes objects due to missing kind data.

**Command Executed:**

```
helm install test-release helm_directory --debug
```

**Output Received**

```
original chart version: ""
Error: installation failed: unable to build Kubernetes object from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: kind not set
```

Interestingly, before attempting the installation, I made sure to run helm lint on my chart directory, and it returned no warnings or errors, implying that my chart's structure and syntax should be correct.

Comment: Please provide an output of `helm template test-release helm_directory` on paste.mozilla.org

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Please include any information needed to reproduce the problem directly in the question – do not include key debugging information only via links to external sites.